# Bird and fish count in cages

Tags: fish, birds

Any technology or application or software to count birds in cages and fishes in tanks easily while conducting inspection.

Am looking for an image software to count birds or fishes directly when a picture is taken of bird cage or fish tanks. Is there any other way besides manual counting?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Usually we expect some kind of question mark or the description of a problem you want to solve. Your post is to be honest really short.

Comment: Did you tried to search for "software count birds from video"? Then I get directly software solutions and a lots of research papers.

Comment: Am looking for an image software to count birds or fishes directly when a picture is taken of bird cage or fish tanks. Is there any other way besides manual counting?

Comment: There are too many options to list.  What machine are you using? what OS? what are you prepared to pay?